# Is the longest chain of non-increasing values in this sequence related to cyclotomic polynomials unbounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cyclotomic-polynomials

The $n$th order cyclotomic polynomial is defined as
$$
\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{\substack{1\le k\le n \\ \gcd(k, n) = 1}}{\left(x - e^{2i\pi k/n}\right)}
$$
Define $c_n$ to be the smallest integer $m$ such that $\Phi_m(x)$ contains a coefficient $\pm n$. It is well known that $c_n$ contains long chains of repeated values, ($c_8 = c_9$, and $c_{10}=c_{10+i}$ for $i = 1\dots4$). Now let $C_n$ be the length of the longest chain of repeated values in $\{c_k\}_{k=1\dots n}$.

**Given the definitions above, is $C_n$ unbounded?**

I have no idea where to even start with this one. Any ideas?

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Your sequence is OEIS [A013594](https://oeis.org/A013594) and also the minimum of [A262404](https://oeis.org/A013594) and [A262405](https://oeis.org/A013594), the related sequences for $+n$ and $-n$, respectively.  The references for those entries and whatever builds on them might be relevant for this question.

Comment: @Saad In my opinion this is not a *no-clue* question. The asker had certainly done their part digging. Off the top of my head the only thing I would have been able to say is that $c_2=105$. I had a vague recollection (confirmed by checking Wikipedia) that $n=23$ is somehow interesting. I can't tell whether this is an interesting research question, but it feels non-trivial to say anything more. It may be turn out to be a poor fit for the Math.SE format, but it is not what I think the phrase "no-clue" seeks to convey.